# OpenVPN - port-share'ing with OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, openvpn

Is it possible to share the same port and ip between OpenVPN (2.2.1) and OpenSSH (5.3) daemons using OpenVPN's share-port option ?

I can't get it to work.. I have openssh listening on all interfaces to port 22 , and an openvpn daemon using TCP protocol on port 443. I've added:

```
port-share 127.0.0.1 22
```

To the conf file that starts that particular openvpn daemon, and restarted it - it starts without errors. But then when I try to ssh into that ip and port from elsewhere in the network it stops:

```
ssh -v -p443 user@host
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host [123.123.123.123] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: loaded 3 keys
```

Is there something I'm missing ? Obviously the port is unblocked, and openvpn continues to work on that port.. I haven't been able to find a working example of OpenVPN + OpenSSH port sharing in my searches, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page I see says that this only works with http/https.  Unless you have found a patch or something I am not aware of?

Man OpenVPN

> --port-share
>
> When run in TCP server mode, share the OpenVPN port with another
>   application, such as an HTTPS server.  If OpenVPN senses a  connection
>   to  its  port which is using a non-OpenVPN protocol, it will proxy the
>   connection to the server at host:port.  **Currently only designed to
>   work with HTTP/HTTPS**, though it would be theoretically possible to
>   extend to other protocols such as ssh.
>
> Not implemented on Windows.

Comment: oh. Fail. I misread that completely :(

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml), a ssl/ssh multiplexer.

From its home page :

> What is it?
>
> sslh accepts HTTPS, SSH, OpenVPN, tinc and XMPP connections on the
>   same port. This makes it possible to connect to any of these servers
>   on port 443 (e.g. from inside a corporate firewall, which almost never
>   block port 443) while still serving HTTPS on that port.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, just make sure

- sshd is listening on the same IP as your port-share setting.

  `#/etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ListenAddress 127.0.0.1 ## 0.0.0.0 is default.
   Port 22`
- If you can't change the ListenAddress. and it was for tunneling purpose, take extra caution on ports setting to avoid port duplications, sshd on 0.0.0.0 will conflict any addresses with the same ports. Therefore if you don't set the direct port or remote port differently than the local port it will conflict.